# Javascript/jQuery focusout event that changes layout causes click event to not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, chaining

I have a field that when you leave focus on it, it changes the layout of the page.  I also have buttons on the page that submit my form.

If I go into my field and type a value, then click the button, the button click event never fires.  This seems to happen because the layout is changing *before* the click event gets fired, which means the button changes places.  By the time the click event fires, it's firing on an empty area, not the button.

Here is a jsfiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/xM88p/

I figured out a way to solve this for IE but after extensive research I can't find/access the same object in FF/Chrome:

```
//only works in IE

if(event.originalEvent.toElement){
  $("#"+event.originalEvent.toElement.id).click();
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between the IE fix and manually triggering the click: `$("#btn_test").click();` ?  I mean, why is one preferable to the other? (Why not just trigger the click?)

Comment: There are multiple buttons and links on the page that would impact this, so I would need to know the ID of the element the user just clicked to ensure I'm triggering the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xM88p/2/

Use `mousedown` instead of `click`:

```
$("#btn_test").on('mousedown', function (event){
    alert("clicked!"); 
});

$('#test').focusout(function (event){
    $('<p>Test</p>').insertAfter(this);
});
```

**Edit**

Okay, I got a little more creative with the event handlers. [The new solution](http://jsfiddle.net/xM88p/7/) keeps track of mousedown/mouseup events as well as the position of the click. It uses these values to check whether mouse up should execute an alert.

```
var testClicked = false;
var lastX, lastY;

$(document).on('mouseup', function (event) {
    if (testClicked === true && lastX === event.clientX && lastY === event.clientY) {
        alert("clicked!"); 
    }
    testClicked = false;
    lastX = null;
    lastY = null;
});

$("#btn_test").on('mousedown', function (event){
    testClicked = true;
    lastX = event.clientX;
    lastY = event.clientY;
});

$('#test').focusout(function (event){
    $('<p>Test</p>').insertAfter(this);
});
```

Comment: generally we'd use mouseup, so if the user forgets something, they know to drag the mouse off the element to cancel the click

Comment: My concern is similar to pythonians, if a user clicks the button but holds their mouse down (and decides they don't want to click the button anymore) they should be able to drag their mouse away without submitting the form.

Comment: That's true, but this is a bit of a special case. Forcing a "click" trigger seems like a worse solution than just using mousedown.

Comment: I agree with you there, mousedown definitely seems to be the better solution of the two.  I was just hoping there's a way to preserve the ability to mousedown and move your mouse off the button and not trigger a form submit, looking like that may not be possible though.

Comment: The problem is that there's no way to tell whether the user intentionally moved the mouse away before releasing the mouse or if the button itself moved away from the mouse. There may be more creative solutions, but any solution involving event handlers will have to solve this discrepancy.

Comment: Okay, I revised my solution. This seems to do what you want without taking away the advantage of mouseup. Let me know if this has any problems.