# Single user action firing two events - second event doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I’m running into this issue where a single action by the user is supposed to trigger two events but it only triggers the first one.

**The scenario:**

A user enters some text into a special field that **modifies the layout** on focusout , after entering the text, without leaving the field, they click a button.

**What’s happening?**

I have a focusout event on a text box and click event on a button.  What I see is the focusout event gets fired but the click event never does.

I’ve encapsulated this in a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fCz6X/13/

```
$('#theText').focusout(function (){
    $("#focusevent").text("Focusevent");
    console.log("focus");
});

$('#theButton').click(function (){
    $("#clickevent").text("Clickevent");
    console.log("click");
});
```

So if you click in the text field then click the button I’d expect both events to fire, but we only see the focus out event.

I put in a temporary fix for this by having the mousedown event fire the button instead of a click event (this fires before the focusout event) but that is causing some other behaviors and issues that I don’t want to see.  Due to those I think optimal solution is finding a way to get the focusout and click events to both fire.  Does anyone have thoughts on how to fix this problem?

**Edit:** After seeing initial responses I dug a little deeper, the issue here is that the focusout event is changing the page layout which very slightly pushes the location of the button down. The click event triggers after the focusout is done but since the button is no longer in the exact same location, nothing happens.

Here is an updated fiddle that shows my problem
http://jsfiddle.net/fCz6X/11/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fCz6X/8/ use console.log

Comment: Changed your code to add text to the page insted of alerting - works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fCz6X/9/)

Comment: @MikeW The text has to actually move the button slightly, ex) http://jsfiddle.net/fCz6X/10/

Comment: Have changed the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fCz6X/12/) to do that, and the Click event no longer fires. Just thinking about that...

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339089/javascript-jquery-focusout-event-that-changes-layout-causes-click-event-to-not-f)

Comment: The answer there is getting close, the only thing left is I have more than one button so I would need the mouseup there to do different things in different situations, is that possible?  http://jsfiddle.net/xM88p/45/  basically the mouseup is too generic right now - is there a way I could figure out the id of the button?

Comment: Within the mousedown event handler `this.id` is the id of the button.

Comment: Perfect, thank you @MikeEdwards! One last question about this, since I'm not using click anymore, using enter or space on the button when it's in focus no longer triggers it.  Is there an easy workaround / solution to that?  Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're calling `alert` - the `focusout` event fires, but before the browser recognizes you've clicked the button, the alert box blocks it.

Change your event handler to `console.log` or something else that's non-obtrusive and you'll be ok.

Comment: Thanks, after digging a little deeper I see the actual problem.  My focusout event is actually doing some custom eventing and handling a request and response, the click event is submitting a form.  I think the issue may actually have to do with the layout of the page changing.  The button is no longer in the same place after the focusout event happens so the click event doesn't trigger anything.  Let me see if I can encapsulate that in a new fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because the `focusout` event fires first, executing the handler, and the `alert` then prevents the browser from recognizing the click.

Try again with `console.log` instead of `alert` - it's less invasive.

Comment: what do you mean by registers?  If you mean the event handler is not created that's not correct.  If you mean that the browser hasn't recognized that a click has occurred then yes.  Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I meant that the browser didn't recognize the click event.  I'll update my answer to be more clear.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Joe said, the blocking alert call is what is breaking the event.  Using a non-blocking call you will see both events.

If you really need to perform an alert like this, though, you can defer calling 'alert' until later using setTimeout()

```
$('#theText').focusout(function (){
    setTimeout(function() { // alert after all events have resolved
        alert("focus left text box");
    }, 0);
});
```

**Edit:** In your updated fiddle the reason the click event never fires is because *no click event occurs*.  If you move the button out from under the mouse on mousedown, there is no followup mouseup which is what initiates the 'click' event.

You may need to reconsider other aspects of your design.  Your solution of using 'mousedown' is the best you can achieve because it's the only event that actually occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Alert that is blocking.
Some browser security prevents firing too many window.alert at the time.

When trying with other triggers, it looks. You may try `console.log()`

```
$('#theText').on("focusout",function (){
    $("#theText").val($("#theText").val()+"flb");   
});

$('#theButton').on("click",function (){
    $("#theText").val($("#theText").val()+"but");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in which the **focusout** function seemed to be preventing the **click** event from firing.

A **click** event consists of both a **mousedown** and a **mouseup** event. If a click invokes a **focusout** for the previous element, the **focusout** event occurs after the **mousedown** event and before the **mouseup** event of the subsequent element.

In my case, my **focusout** function invokes an action using the fetch API, during which an animated image is displayed on an overlay. The overlay prevented the **mouseup** event from being registered for the original element so that only the **mousedown** event was registered; no **click** event was produced.

My solution was (1) to set a global variable preserving a reference to the original element clicked and (2) to add a **mouseup** listener to the image overlay (whose id is "wait") to invoke the original element's **click** method (in those instances in which the click was released while the overlay was still visible):

The function invoked by the **focusout** event, which calls the fetch API wrapper, must include its related element as a parameter:

```
// function called by a focusout event
function myResponse(e) {
  myRequest = 'whatever';
  return myFetch('save.php', myRequest, true, e.relatedTarget).then(response => {
...
}
```

The element clicked is set to a global variable:

```
let relatedTarget;
// simulate the original click
function finishClick(e) {
  if (relatedTarget) {
    relatedTarget.click();
    relatedTarget = null;
  }
}
// but not if both mousedown and mouseup registered on the overlay
function unsetRelatedTarget(e) {
  relatedTarget = null;
}

// custom wrapper for fetch API
async function myFetch(page, request, wait, relatedTargetParam) {
  if (wait) {
    wait = document.getElementById('wait');
    if (wait) {
      wait.style.display = 'block';
      if (relatedTargetParam) {
        relatedTarget = relatedTargetParam;
        wait.addEventListener('mousedown', unsetRelatedTarget);
        wait.addEventListener('mouseup', finishClick);
      }
    }
  }
  return await fetch(page,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      body: request
    }
  ).then(response => {
...
```

An alternate solution is to use merely a **mousedown** event instead of a **click** event when there is a possibility of a **focusout** event interrupting the click. A downside to this solution is that a user can no longer abort the **click** event by moving the mouse away from the element before releasing the clicker.